# Function App and storage queue. How to do retry correctly

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

We have a Function App v1 triggered by a storage queue. In the documentation the following is stated:

> maxDequeueCount   5
>   The number of times to try processing a message before moving it to the poison queue.

As I understand this, then the function app will restart and run if something goes wrong for 5 times and the to poison queue. But what does wrong mean? Is it if the Function App throws an unhandled exception?Or do you need do something else? We would actually like the function app to retry, but right now we catch any exception. We do this because we experienced that an unhandled exception can sometimes stop all running instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retry will be triggered while you azure function throws an exception and maxDequeueCount <= 5.